"no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'Diem2D')"
enter image description here
i tried to used operator istream and ostream but it doesn't work. I'm writing a HinhTron class from the existing Diem2D class to use point coordinates from the 2D class. How can i fix that? Should i use operator?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Where is [mcve]?
